# JSON parsing from ALPHA VANTAGE API

Tags: json

I getting some stock data from ALPHA VANTAGE Api . I did get the whole JSON data but i am having problem with getting specific which is the low , high and open portions of the "Time Series (Daily)": This is my code:
  func updateStockData (json: JSON) {

```
    if json["Time Series (Daily)"].string != nil {
      let open = json["Time Series (Daily)"][0][0]
      print("open======open")
      print(open)
      let high = json["Time Series (Daily)"][0][1]
      print(high)
      let low = json["Time Series (Daily)"][0][2]
      print(low)
        self.pricePriceLabel.text = "Open: " + open.string! + "$"

         self.highLable.text = "High: " + high.string! + "$"

        self.lowLabel.text = "Low: " + low.string! + "$"
    } else {
         self.bitcoinPriceLabel.text = "Unavailable"
          self.lowLabel.text = "Unavailable"
          self.highLable.text = "Unavailable"
    }
```

And this is the json data that i have to grap from:

```
 {
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "HBAN",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-07-09 15:54:10",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2019-07-09": {
        "1. open": "13.6400",
        "2. high": "13.8900",
        "3. low": "13.6000",
        "4. close": "13.8500",
        "5. volume": "5543590"
    },
    "2019-07-08": {
        "1. open": "13.8000",
        "2. high": "13.9000",
        "3. low": "13.6600",
        "4. close": "13.7300",
        "5. volume": "10355636"
    },
    "2019-07-05": {
        "1. open": "13.9500",
        "2. high": "14.1600",
        "3. low": "13.8400",
        "4. close": "13.9200",
        "5. volume": "7398341"
    },.......
```

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is likely using a pandas data frame as they are significantly easier to navigate.

```
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# FUNCTIONS FOR ALPHA VANTAGE
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY = 'TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY'
TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED = 'TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED'
TIME_SERIES_DAILY = 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY'
TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED = 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED'
TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY = 'TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY'
TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY_ADJUSTED = 'TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY_ADJUSTED'
TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY = 'TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY'
TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY_ADJUSTED = 'TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY_ADJUSTED'

# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# TIME SERIES FOR STOCK DATA
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ONEMIN = 'Time Series (1min)'
FIVEMIN = 'Time Series (5min)'
FIVETEENMIN = 'Time Series (15min)'
THIRTYMIN = 'Time Series (30min)'
HOUR = 'Time Series (60min)'
FIVEMIN = 'Time Series (5min)'
DAILY = 'Time Series (Daily)' 
WEEKLY = 'Weekly Time Series'
WEEKLY_ADJ = 'Weekly Adjusted Time Series'
MONTLY = 'Monthly Time Series'
MONTLY_ADJ = 'Monthly Adjusted Time Series'

# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# query timeseries stock data of selected type ////////////
# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
def query_timeseries_data(func, symbol, outputsize='full', datatype='json', apikey='YOURKEYHERE'):
    data = {
        "function": func, # Here you can put any of the 'funcs' above
        "symbol": symbol,
        "outputsize": outputsize, # (full) and (compact) are accepted
        "datatype": datatype,
        "apikey": apikey
    }
    return requests.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query", data).json()

# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# convert timeseries stock data of selected type to json //
# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
def get_timeseries_dataframe(json, type):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json[type], orient= 'index')
    df.index =  pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
    
    df = df.rename(columns={ '1. open': 'Open', '2. high': 'High', '3. low': 'Low', '4. close': 'Close', '5. volume': 'Volume'})
    df = df.astype({'Open': 'float64', 'High': 'float64', 'Low': 'float64','Close': 'float64','Volume': 'float64',})
    df = df[[ 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]
    return df

# Now all you have to do is actually call the funcs
response_json = query_timeseries_data(TIME_SERIES_DAILY, 'MSFT')
sockprice_dataframe = get_timeseries_dataframe(response_json, DAILY)
```

I found this code on another thread and made it a bit easier to use, it's super effective

Answer (score 0):

The data is not an array, it is all objects, so you will need to refer to the elements by key, not by their index. Here is your code adjusted to suit:

```
if json["Time Series (Daily)"].string != nil {
  // Flatten the object keys and take the first one
  const firstDate = Object.keys(json["Time Series (Daily)"][0])
  let open = json["Time Series (Daily)"][firstDate]["1. open"]
  print("open======open")
  print(open)
  let high = json["Time Series (Daily)"][firstDate]["2. high"]
  print(high)
  let low = json["Time Series (Daily)"][firstDate]["3. low"]
  print(low)
    self.pricePriceLabel.text = "Open: " + open.string! + "$"

     self.highLable.text = "High: " + high.string! + "$"

    self.lowLabel.text = "Low: " + low.string! + "$"
} else {
     self.bitcoinPriceLabel.text = "Unavailable"
      self.lowLabel.text = "Unavailable"
      self.highLable.text = "Unavailable"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey below is a function I wrote to easily extract historical stock prices from Alpha Vantage. All you have to do is plug in your symbol and token. For more functions on extracting Alpha Vantage data, feel free to check out my link: https://github.com/hklchung/StockPricePredictor/blob/master/2020/alphavantage_funcs.py

```
def request_stock_price_hist(symbol, token, sample = False):
    if sample == False:
        q_string = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol={}&outputsize=full&apikey={}'
    else:
        q_string = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol={}&apikey={}'

    print("Retrieving stock price data from Alpha Vantage (This may take a while)...")
    r = requests.get(q_string.format(symbol, token))
    print("Data has been successfully downloaded...")
    date = []
    colnames = list(range(0, 7))
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = colnames)
    print("Sorting the retrieved data into a dataframe...")
    for i in tqdm(r.json()['Time Series (Daily)'].keys()):
        date.append(i)
        row = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r.json()['Time Series (Daily)'][i], orient='index').reset_index().T[1:]
        df = pd.concat([df, row], ignore_index=True)
    df.columns = ["open", "high", "low", "close", "adjusted close", "volume", "dividend amount", "split cf"]
    df['date'] = date
    return df
```